# Branch.io only count "Clicks"

Tags: count, click, branch.io

I use Branch.io for tracking people when they click the link in my page, after that if they already have the app. Branch.io open it, if not Branch.io will redirect to store for download
but in dashboard.branch.io I can see only total clicks. It not tracking when people open app or open store to download.
Thanks for reading!

[Branch.io only count "Clicks"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjDu7.jpg)

Comment: Have you added the Branch SDK in your app. Only when the SDK is integrated correctly as per the guide [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/) which Branch be able to attribute app installs and app opens.

Comment: Hello Amruta. 
Thanks for the reply to my question. I already config like that in my android app before I push question. Can you check that for me? 
https://github.com/tuanngocptn/draft/blob/master/build.gradle
https://github.com/tuanngocptn/draft/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml
That file I copy from the project, edit name and key.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this problem for about 3 days and finally I find out that the problem was from my account. I think because of inactivity or other issues, my account was disabled (only install and re-open section) or maybe another issue.
By the way **Creating a New Account** and make link solved my problem.

Note: Tutorial in **SetupSDK** in Dashboard is not enough! after set the links, in your setting, do other works from [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/).

Feel free to ask questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

Installs will be counted only the first time an app launches for a given IDFA/AAID. (Excludes cases where the IDFA is reset with the app still installed.). You can enable re-installs column on the Sources section to check re-installs.

Comment: Thank for answer
Reinstall column doesn't count like install column.
And can your share document for IDFA/AAID for this case
That is a new word for me.
Realy thanks.